# How can I use a method as a decorator in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class that utilizes a connection to a database to interact with the data like this:

```py
class DataBase:
    def __init__(self, user, password):
        # open connection in init to have only one active connection per class instance
        self.connection = Connection(user, password)

    def get(self):
        with self.connection:
            # get data magic
            pass
    
    def post(self):
        with self.connection:
            # post data magic
            pass
```

To avoid writing `with self.connection` for all methods, I would like to add a decorator like this:

```py
class DataBase:
    def __init__(self, user, password):
        # open connection in init to have only one active connection per class instance
        self.connection = Connection(user, password)
    
    def _with_connection(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            with self.connection:
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return result
        return wrapper
    
    @_with_connection
    def get(self):
        # get data magic
        pass
        
    @_with_connection
    def post(self):
        # post data magic
        pass
```

However, this obviously raises the following problem: `TypeError: _with_connection() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'`

So how could this be implemented?

Comment: How is decorating every method an improvement over using an explicit `with` statement? You're just replacing a line from the method body with a line decorating the method.

Comment: In this particular case it would only improve readability. However, this is only a simple example for more complex implentations of the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you aren't using `_with_connection` as an instance method (never mind that you *can't*, because no instance of `Database` exists yet), so it shouldn't be defined like one. Get rid of the `self` parameter. It *is* used in `wrapper`, so you can define that separately from `*args`.

```
class DataBase:
    def __init__(self, user, password):
        # open connection in init to have only one active connection per class instance
        self.connection = Connection(user, password)
    
    def _with_connection(func):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with self.connection:
                result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            return result
        return wrapper
    
    @_with_connection
    def get(self):
        # get data magic
        pass
        
    @_with_connection
    def post(self):
        # post data magic
        pass
```

I don't see this as any kind of improvement over your original code, though. You aren't saving any lines of code (replacing the `with` statement with a decoration), and you make it less obvious how `get` and `post` actually use the connection.

Comment: Okay, this works, thanks! :D But why? I thought the first argument of a method is automatically used as `self`. My IDE even raises a warning because it thinks that I `func(self, *args, **kwargs)` is actuallu calling "self"

Comment: `_with_connection` is a regular function, being called as such. A method only comes into existence when you access the function as an attribute of an instance (e.g., `self._with_connection`). The details of how that works is spelled out in the [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

Comment: In short, *all* "methods" are just `function`-valued class attributes. When accessed as attributes, the `function`'s `__get__` method is called and returns an instance of `method`, which when called pass its own arguments along with the object to the underlying function. `foo.meth(x)` is essentially shorthand for `type(foo).__dict__['meth'].__get__(foo, type(foo))(x)`. (You can see why the shorthand is more popular :) )